# how to determine when a request in completed in mootools?

Tags: javascript, ajax, mootools, mootools1.2

I am new to moootools and I am creating a Template class,This is my code -

```
var Template = new Class({
  Singleton : true,
  template : '',

  /* gets the component type template */
  get : function(componentType){
    var tplUrl = Core.getUrl('backend') + 'response/' + componentType + '/get_template.php',
        that = this,
        request = new Request({url: tplUrl, method : 'get',onSuccess : function(responseText){
          that.template = responseText; 
          return that;
        }}).send(); 
  }

});
```

What I want to do is this :

```
var tpl = new Template();
tpl.get('component').setTemplateData({name:'yosy'});
```

The problem is when I am calling this code :

```
var tpl = new Template();
console.log( tpl.get('component') );
```

I am not getting my current Template object,I am getting is 'undefined'.
How I can make this chainable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making an asynchronous call inside the `get` function. The request may take 100ms, 1s or 10s and by the time the `get` function finishes and returns, the request will still be pending. Instead what you need to do is, pass a callback function to `get` and call that on success.

```
get: function(componentType, successCallback) {
    var request = new Request({
        ..,
        onSuccess: successCallback
    }).send();
}
```

Note that you are not returning anything from the get function. One example way to invoke this would be:

```
tpl.get('component', function(responseText) { alert(responseText); });
```

Comment: to make it chainable he can also turn into into a synchronous request, although it defeats the purpose :)

Comment: I've stopped recommending the synchronous option :) but good alternatives would be this concept of [futures and promises](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises), and the [async method queues](http://www.dustindiaz.com/async-method-queues/) by Dustin Diaz.

Answer (score -1):

Your get function is missing a return value. If you want functions to chain you should return the object itself:

```
get : function(componentType){
var tplUrl = Core.getUrl('backend') + 'response/' + componentType + '/get_template.php',
    that = this,
    request = new Request({url: tplUrl, method : 'get',onSuccess : function(responseText){
      that.template = responseText; 
      return that;
    }}).send(); 

    return this;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if returning the current object or the request will be on any help here. `get` probably needs a callback for when the component loads.

Comment: But I want to return the object when I done loading the request.